# Axon message types

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I have two spring boot apps, let's say `A` and `B`. `A` sends a message through rabbitMQ to `B`.

If the event classes for `A` and `B` are not in the same package (i.e in both `A` and `B` the events are in `com.events`), the messages are not processed.

How can I avoid having the same packages across multiple apps?

Receiver `application.properties`:

```
axon.eventhandling.processors.amqpEvents.source=rabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource
axon.eventhandling.processors.amqpEvents.mode=SUBSCRIBING
```

Sender `application.properties`:

```
axon.amqp.exchange=spring-boot-exchange
```

Comment: Can You share your application.yml file ?

Comment: Im using simple application.properties Receiving app: axon.eventhandling.processors.amqpEvents.source=rabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource
axon.eventhandling.processors.amqpEvents.mode=SUBSCRIBING and the sender: axon.amqp.exchange=spring-boot-exchange

Answer (score 0):

I have observed the same behaviour using AxonServer instead of Rabbit. My explanation is: this is how default serialization works. I think switching to different serde mechanism would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is indeed independent of the type of messaging infrastructure you are going to use. Whether that's Kafka, AMQP, Pub/Sub or Axon Server, a common grounds of what the message is needs to be shared.

You should regard your messages as the public API actually. Sharing the public API with whomever is going to connect to your applications isn't overly odd to be honest.

Another way to resolve the issue, instead of having a public package for the API, would be to introduce a mapping from [package & type] to [package & type]. This mapping should be incorporated into the `Serializer` you are using (e.g. the `JacksonSerializer` or `XStreamSerializer`). More specifically, you will have to provide a custom `Serializer` overriding the `Serializer#classForType(SerializedType)` method. In this implementation you will then match the received `SerializedType`, validate it and return the `Class` present on the local application's class path.